# Group integers in a given array where no 2 numbers in the same group has a difference more than k. Find the minimum number of groups

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search

I'm working on an assignment and really struggling coming up with a working solution. I will explain the question first and then walk through how I am thinking about the solution.

Question: `Input: List<Integer> nums = [1,5,4,6,8,9,2] k = 3` 
I have to find the minimum number of groups, where no 2 numbers in the same group has a difference more than 3. So, in here, one of the solutions could be `[[1,2,4],[5,6,8],[9]]`. Note that it can also be `[[1,2,4],[5,6],[8,9]]`. Either way minimum number of groups is 3.

My Strategy: I am thinking of using binary search recursive way. To briefly explain what I have been trying to do -

```
- Sort the Array. So it becomes - [1,2,4,5,6,8,9]
- Make left = 0 right = nums.size()-1
- Create base cases 
         - if size of the array is 0 return 0
         - if size of the array is 1 return 1
         - if nums.get(right) - nums.get(left) <= k return 1
- While left < right
        - Make mid = (left+right)/2
        - if (number at mid - number at left) is greater than k
                  -recursively call the function like this, findMinGroup(nums, left, mid-1, k)
-At one point this recursive call will hit one of the base cases and return - either 0 or 1.
-if it returns 1 that means we found a group. if It returns 0 that means in the left side we can not form any group. So we check the right side.
```

This is the code I have written so far,

```
public class GroupNumbers {

    static int minNumGroups = 0;

    public static int minimumGroups(List<Integer> nums, int k){

        Collections.sort(nums);
        System.out.println(nums);

        int left = 0;
        int right = nums.size() == 0 ? nums.size() : nums.size() - 1;

        return findMinGroups(nums, left, right, k);
    }

    private static int findMinGroups(List<Integer> nums, int left, int right, int k){

        if((right - left) == 0)
            return 0;

        if((right - left) == 1 || nums.get(right) - nums.get(left) <= k)
            return 1;

        while(left < right){
            int mid = (left + right)/2;

            if(nums.get(mid) - nums.get(left) > k){
                int group = findMinGroups(nums, left, mid-1, k);
                if(group > 0){
                    minNumGroups += group;
                    left = mid;
                }else{
                    left = (left + right)/2;
                }
            }
        }

        return minNumGroups;
    }
```

I feel like I have the right idea about the solutions, but due to my lack of experience with these type of algorithms, I am not able to fully articulate my thoughts in code. I would really appreciate some help/insight for solving this problem.

Comment: Sorting first is a good idea. But then, you simply have to examine the elements in a row, feeding the groups one by one.

Comment: When you write code, you have to prove to yourself that it works.  Your procedure doesn't work.  I know you want to ask "why not"? But first I'd want to see your proof that it is correct.  I'd be happy to point out the problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

One other simple solution would be iteration over entire list after sorting.

```
public static int minimumGroups(List<Integer> nums, int k){
    int minGrps = 1;
    Collections.sort(nums);
    int numToCmp = nums.get(0);
    for(Integer num : nums) {
      if(num > numToCmp + k) {
        minGrps++;
        numToCmp = num;
      }
    }
    return minGrps;
}
```